# EC2 - IIS and .NET Core - add application I get error Authorization - Cannot verify access to path, HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, .net-core

I want to add application in IIS. I have EC2 instance on AWS Amazon - Windows 2019 Server Base. I want to add application to my folder created in wwwroot folder. When I press test I get error:

```
Authorization Cannot verify access to path (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp)
```

Authentication is ok

I was looking in the Internet and I've installed everything in IIS.

And when I go to my website `http://localhost/myapp/` I have error:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error       
Config File    \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\web.config

Requested URL      http://localhost:80/myapp/
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
```

Comment: That test fails for almost everyone, so you should ignore it.

Comment: Error 0x8007000d means URL rewriting module is missing or proper version is not installed, you can try to check all dependencies from web.config and install them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the error. It was the problem with certificate for Identity server. I had to add certificate and configuration for that in appsettings.json:

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "Certificates\\certificatefile.pfx",
      "Password": "mypsw"
    },
    "Clients": {
      "FtblrApp": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
  },
```

Now it works